# Why are my minesweeper sqaures not clicking the right button?

Tags: python, minesweeper

I've been having a little issue with my code. I am trying to make a minesweeper game. as you know, minesweeper has a reset button and a timer at the top, so I've made my list start 50 from the top, to be able to add them down the line, however, this also means when I click on a square, the square a couple of rows down gets clicked instead.

How can I avoid this? is there a way to make it start lower without the mouse click also being lower? or which values will I need to change for it to accommodate it?

Thank you

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0) 
WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 20 
MARGIN = 5 
grid = []
for row in range(10):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append(0)
print(grid)

pygame.init()
 
WINDOW_SIZE = [255, 265]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
 
pygame.display.set_caption("Array Backed Grid")
 
done = False
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            done = True 
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
            row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)
            grid[row][column] = 1
            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)
 
    screen.fill(BLACK)
 
    for row in range(10):
        for column in range(10):
            color = WHITE
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                color = GREEN
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * (column) + MARGIN,
                              50+(MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                              WIDTH,
                              HEIGHT])
 

    clock.tick(60)
 

    pygame.display.flip()
 

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Instead of

    column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)

you probably want 

    column = (pos[0]-MARGIN) // WIDTH

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid Y starts at 50, so subtract 50 from the mouse position when determining the row.

```
row = (pos[1]-50) // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)
```

Also add 50 to your window size to see the entire grid.

```
WINDOW_SIZE = [255, 315]
```